# can't open “VCASAND.lib” or can't find clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll

Tags: visual-studio, address-sanitizer

I try to build an open source project with visual studio 2022, but it fails with "can't open “VCASAND.lib” ", I searched it by tool `everything`, that file is not exist. I don't know what to do, I googled it, no directly answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `visual studio installer` install `c++ AddressSanitizer`, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170